# Server/Client sockets and ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, sockets

**Server:**

```
   Socket client_socket = server_back_end.server_socket.accept(); //1.

   ClientInfo new_client = new ClientInfo(
    new ObjectOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream()), //writer
    new ObjectInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream()),   //reader
    "blah, about to be re-written"
  );

 new_client.user_name = (String) new_client.reader.readObject(); //3. "bob"
 //new_client.user_name = new_client.reader.readLine(); //this doesnt work either

 System.out.println("Client " + new_client.user_name + " has connected.");
```

---

**Client:**

```
Socket client_socket = new Socket();
client_socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(server_ip, server_port), 500);
client_front_end.display("<<Connection Successful.>>\n");

String user_name = txtfield.getText(); //"bob"

client = new ClientInfo(
   new ObjectOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream()), //writer
   new ObjectInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream()),   //reader
   user_name);

client.writer.writeChars(client.user_name); //2.
```

---

I first run the server code. When I step through the debugger on the server side, "//1." executes, and waits for a client to connect.

Then I run the client code. What I expect to happen is "//2." should call "//3." in the server code, pick up the name, and print that the user has connected. But  the 
`ObjectOutputStream.writeChars(client.user_name)` is not triggering the read in the server. What am I doing wrong? My goal is to successfully print the name from the client using these ObjectOutput/ObjectInput streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading an object but you aren't writing an object. You're writing chars. `readObject()` can only read the output of `writeObject()`. `readInt()` can only read the output of `writeInt()`. And so on.

Comment: I understand the concept you are saying, but aren't I writing a string and then reading an object that gets casted to a string? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: updated the original post to reflect another thing I tried

Comment: I can only repeat. If you want to read with `readObject()` you have to write with `writeObject()`.

Comment: Got it! THANK YOU!